# Why would MySQL Workbench Table Data Import Wizard import 0 records?

Tags: mysql, csv, import, mysql-workbench

I'm very inexperienced with MySQL and I'm having a lot of problems.  I'm using MySQL Workbench 6.3 on Linux Mint 17.3.

I'm trying to import a CSV file into a table using the Table Data Import Wizard.  This works fine for a simple table but is failing for a more complex table.

I'm correcting everything in the import wizard to make sure each row and column is perfect.  It seems to work at first, importing my ~14000 rows takes time, there's disk activity and no errors are reported, but at the end:

"0 records imported"

and the table remains blank as before.

Frustratingly if I import into a *new* table everything works as expected.  I notice that the data types are quite different though.  I've tried to force the data types in the .CSV file to correspond to what is expected.  I also made sure that "NULLABLE=NO" fields did have something in them.  But if I broke any of these rules, wouldn't there be errors?  I even tried importing just one line, thinking that maybe somewhere in this largish table there's some bad data, but I can't even import one line.

Why would there be no errors, yet "0 records imported" into an existing table, but everything works fine with a new table?

My apologies in advance if I did not include enough information.

Thank you.

Comment: *the data types are quite different* is meaningful. What sort of differences? Why not import the data into that new table, and then import from there to your real table doing any necessary data type conversions in the process?

Comment: The differences are that the existing table uses "varchar" or "timestamp" data types where the new table uses "text".  Also the new table uses "int" and "bigint" while the exiting one uses "double" and there's one instance of "bit".  I'll learn about trying to import from one table to another while converting data types, it might be easier now that they're both valid MySQL tables.  Thank you Ken.

Comment: So it turned out that there were lots of problems with the data.  Just converting it wasn't enough.  I eventually went into "alter table" and tried to alter each column's attributes to get the two tables to match.  This resulted in finding lots of NULL values when I set "NOT NULL", then lots of duplicates when I set "UNIQUE".  After rectifying those, there were still some references to UUIDs in other tables, then I also discovered that one column expected UUIDs rather than just unique numbers.  Finally when the two tables matched I imported the new data into the existing table.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to import ~2000 records in each import. I believe there is a memory issue with the DB. I came across the same situation and I was uploading ~9000 records. Everything including datatypes were perfect.